# angularjs module and controller does not work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create module and controller for understanding the basic concept. I'm using this version  `AngularJS v1.5.0` of angular js. I tried below code but it does not work.

```
<div ng-app="fModule" ng-controller="fController">
    {{ country + "" + city  }}
</div>

var newModule = angulr.module("fModule",[]);
app.controller("fController",function($region){
    $region.country = "Pakistan";
    $region.city = "Karachi";   
});
```

But above code does not work, it just returns me same variables `{{ country + "" + city }}` instead of values. Can any one guide me where i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo:

```
var newModule = angulr.module("fModule",[]);
```

Change it to:

```
var newModule = angular.module("fModule",[]);
```

And when you declare your app as `newModule`, you'll also need to use it when declaring your controller:

```
newModule.controller("fController",function($region){
```

And if you're injecting `$region` make sure is defined/loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the use of $region. But in angular js we have a concept of $scope. So your code should work if you replace the $region with $scope.

Apart from that some typo in module definition **angulr** to **angular**

Other thing is if you defined the module name with **newModule** then you have to use the defined module to add controller and services.

So in controller definition **app** to **newModule**

```
var newModule = angular.module("fModule",[]);
newModule.controller("fController",function($scope){
    $scope.country = "Pakistan";
    $scope.city = "Karachi";   
});
```

For more details on scope please go through it

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the $region used for?  Do u use factory or services? . Anyway if you want to display the city and country in view you should use $scope.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/um8p6pd7/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
   <div ng-controller="fModule">
    {{ country + " " + city  }}
   </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 angular.module('test', []);
 angular.module('test').controller('fModule', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.country = "Pakistan";
    $scope.city = "Karachi"; 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even bind your controller to your module. Your module variable name is `newModule` and you define a controller to a variable called `app` which I'm not sure if you have even declared that. Thus it can't get any values from your controller. So change following:

`app.controller (....)`

to

`newModule.controller (.....)`